# How to mock nanoid for testing?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock nanoid for my testing but it doesn't seem to be working.

my function

```
  public async createApp(appDto: ApplicationDto): Promise<string> {
    const appWithToken = { ...appDto, accessToken: nanoid() };
    const application = await this.applicationModel.create(appWithToken);

    return application.id;
  }
```

My test:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockRepository.create.mockResolvedValueOnce({ id: mockId });
  });

  test("creates application and returns an id", async () => {
    const mockAppDto: ApplicationDto = { email: "123@mock.com" };
    const application = await applicationService.createApplication(mockAppDto);

    expect(mockRepository.create).toHaveBeenCalledWith(mockAppDto); //how do I mock the nanoid here?
    expect(application).toBe(mockId);
  });
```

So basically I'm struggling to figure out how to mock the nanoid which is generated inside the function.

I've tried the following at the top of the file:

```
jest.mock('nanoid', () => 'mock id');
```

however it doesn't work at all.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't mock the [nanoid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nanoid) module correctly. It uses named exports to export the `nanoid` function.

Use [jest.mock(moduleName, factory, options)](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) is correct, the `factory` argument is optional. It will create a mocked `nanoid` function.

Besides, you can use the `mocked` function from `ts-jest/utils` to handle the TS type.

E.g.

`Example.ts`:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';

export interface ApplicationDto {}

export class Example {
  constructor(private applicationModel) {}

  public async createApp(appDto: ApplicationDto): Promise<string> {
    const appWithToken = { ...appDto, accessToken: nanoid() };
    const application = await this.applicationModel.create(appWithToken);

    return application.id;
  }
}
```

`Example.test.ts`:

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid';
import { Example, ApplicationDto } from './Example';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('nanoid');

const mnanoid = mocked(nanoid);

describe('67898249', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    mnanoid.mockReturnValueOnce('mock id');
    const mockAppDto: ApplicationDto = { email: '123@mock.com' };
    const mockApplicationModel = { create: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce({ id: 1 }) };
    const example = new Example(mockApplicationModel);
    const actual = await example.createApp(mockAppDto);
    expect(actual).toEqual(1);
    expect(mockApplicationModel.create).toBeCalledWith({ email: '123@mock.com', accessToken: 'mock id' });
  });
});
```

test result:

```
 PASS  examples/67898249/Example.test.ts (9.134 s)
  67898249
    ✓ should pass (4 ms)

------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File        | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files   |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Example.ts |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.1 s
```

Comment: I get an error `cannot find module 'ts-jest/utils'`

Comment: @FiddleFreak https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72960399/ts-jest-utils-missing

Comment: Just adding this to the test file works in 2023. `jest.mock("nanoid", () => {
  return { nanoid: () => "123" }
});`