# TS-Jest utils missing

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

Well, using `ts-jest` `27.x.x`, I could access the `utils` helper by `require('ts-jest/utils')`, and as you can see in the below picture, it was present in the ts-jest dependency folder:
[image: ts-jest 27]

But in a newer project using `ts-jest` `28.x.x`, when I try to import that, this is the result:
[image: error import]

And this is the ts-jest dependency folder:
[image: ts-jest 28]

What should I do now to use those helpers?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

See [Test helpers](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/27.1/guides/test-helpers) doc about the `mocked` test helper:

> This function is now deprecated and will be removed in **28.0.0**. The function has been integrated into `jest-mock` package as a part of Jest **27.4.0**, see https://github.com/facebook/jest/pull/12089. Please use the one from `jest-mock` instead.

You should use [jest.mocked(item: T, deep = false)](https://jestjs.io/docs/27.x/jest-object#jestmockedtitem-t-deep--false) instead of `import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils'`

From `ts-jest` 28.0.0, they remove `ts-jest/utils` sub path export. See this [issue](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/pull/3334)

> We are exporting everything from `index.ts` so `utils` now can be removed.

Comment: I was actually looking for the `pathsToModuleNameMapper` method which was available in `ts-jest/utils`, however just like you said, it is indeed available in the index :D thank you my friend!

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
import { mocked } from "ts-jest/utils";
```

with

```
import { mocked } from "jest-mock";
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try putting that file in the `setupFilesAfterEnv` option in the jest config?

Comment: no need for that. as our friend @slideshowp2 said, everything i needed from `/utils` was actually available in the `ts-jest` itself.

Comment: Cool. Very helpful post!